# Will impeachment have to precede criminal charges against the president of the US?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, impeachment, official-immunity

Lets say the president of the US kills a person.  Would he first have to be impeached before his murder trail can begin or do criminal charges against him happen the same way as with anyone else? Or is it the case that the president doing certain crimes auto-impeaches him when found guilty?

Comment: This question may be better suited to the politics SE. I await guidance from community members

Comment: @ Neil Meyer I for one think this belongs on Law.se, but there is already a full answer, please follow the link.